# Mongo Query Slow Log - How to optimize

Tags: mongodb

Query 1:

```
db.test1 command: find { find: "test1", filter: { company: ObjectId('xyz'), author: ObjectId('abc'), aggregated: false, as_of_date: { $gte: new Date(1420070400000) } }, $db: "data", $readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { aggregated: 1 } keysExamined:78445 docsExamined:78445 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:612 nreturned:0 reslen:100 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1226 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 613 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 613 } } } protocol:op_msg 121ms
```

Collection Count -> 399,999,999 Documents ( Approx Value )

Query2:

```
db.test2 command: find { find: "test2", filter: { as_of_date: { $gte: new Date(1644969600000) }, holdings_type: "etf", issuer: "ABCD", ticker: "EFG", cusip: "HIJK", author: ObjectId('xyz'), company: ObjectId('abc') }, $db: "data", $readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { author: 1 } keysExamined:94587 docsExamined:94587 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:738 nreturned:2 reslen:576 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1478 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 739 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 739 } } } protocol:op_msg 194ms
```

Collection Count -> 3,399,999,999 Documents ( Approx Value )

Can you help me optimize this query.
I have created Index on each field in Both Collections.
I don't have created Compound Indexes. Will that solve the problem or is there any other solution?

Comment: How long does it take and which time do you expect? You read almost 100k  documents - how can you expect this may run in a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Previously this was using only one index for finding.
After I created compound index, now query is approx 20ms - 50ms.
But, I am still looking for better solution as compound indexing takes huge amount of space.